# Use Google Cloud backend with GCM for android version before ICE CREAM SANDWICH

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-messaging

I tried to follow [this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/cloud/samples/mbs/deploy_backend) to deploy backend with `Google Cloud Engine`, then I follow [this](https://developers.google.com/cloud/samples/mbs/android/) and [this](https://developers.google.com/cloud/samples/mbs/android/enable_push) to register push notification with `GCM` to run the sample project and got the success. 
The problem is my app need to support android version 2.2+ (api level 8), but the cloud backend require minimum API level of 15 (`ICE CREAM SANDWICH MR1`).
 
I tried to set api level down to 8, then replace all fragments and activities with the support package library, but it gave me an exception `Failure delivering result` on runtime:

```
   02-15 13:41:23.266: E/AndroidRuntime(5209): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   02-15 13:41:23.266: E/AndroidRuntime(5209): Process: com.google.cloud.backend, PID: 5209
   02-15 13:41:23.266: E/AndroidRuntime(5209): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=0, data=null} to activity {com.google.cloud.backend/com.google.cloud.backend.sample.guestbook.GuestbookActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
   02-15 13:41:23.266: E/AndroidRuntime(5209):  at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3488)
   02-15 13:41:23.266: E/AndroidRuntime(5209):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3531)
   02-15 13:41:23.266: E/AndroidRuntime(5209):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:157)
   02-15 13:41:23.266: E/AndroidRuntime(5209):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1295)
   02-15 13:41:23.266: E/AndroidRuntime(5209):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   02-15 13:41:23.266: E/AndroidRuntime(5209):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
   02-15 13:41:23.266: E/AndroidRuntime(5209):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293)
   02-15 13:41:23.266: E/AndroidRuntime(5209):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
   02-15 13:41:23.266: E/AndroidRuntime(5209):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
   02-15 13:41:23.266: E/AndroidRuntime(5209):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1259)
   02-15 13:41:23.266: E/AndroidRuntime(5209):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1075)
   02-15 13:41:23.266: E/AndroidRuntime(5209):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
   02-15 13:41:23.266: E/AndroidRuntime(5209): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
   02-15 13:41:23.266: E/AndroidRuntime(5209):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(FragmentManager.java:1343)
   02-15 13:41:23.266: E/AndroidRuntime(5209):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1354)
   02-15 13:41:23.266: E/AndroidRuntime(5209):  at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:595)
   02-15 13:41:23.266: E/AndroidRuntime(5209):  at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:574)
   02-15 13:41:23.266: E/AndroidRuntime(5209):  at com.google.cloud.backend.sample.guestbook.GuestbookActivity.initiateFragments(GuestbookActivity.java:212)
   02-15 13:41:23.266: E/AndroidRuntime(5209):  at com.google.cloud.backend.sample.guestbook.GuestbookActivity.onActivityResult(GuestbookActivity.java:168)
   02-15 13:41:23.266: E/AndroidRuntime(5209):  at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5581)
   02-15 13:41:23.266: E/AndroidRuntime(5209):  at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3484)
```

Is there any alternate way to make it works on android API level less than 15? Since the `GCM` support minimum level 2.2+, from [the document](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gcm.html):

> The GCM-enabled Android application that is running on a device.  This
>   must be a 2.2 Android device that has Google Play Store installed, and
>   it must have at least one logged in Google account if the device is
>   running a version lower than Android 4.0.4.  Alternatively, for
>   testing you can use an emulator running Android 2.2 with Google APIs.

**Update**: I just run [this example](http://developers.google.com/cloud/samples/repository/mbs/android) from Google and change all `Fragment` to  `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` and `Activity` to     `android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity` because I change minSdkVersion to 8 in manifest.

Comment: You should post the code the causes this error. That would allow people to help you.

Comment: @Eran I updated my question. The source code is google 's example, I just modify min sdk to 8 and replace all `fragments` & `activities` with the ones in support package.